# how to install yum in centos6.6

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

I use centOS 6.6:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

I need OS version updates. But at this time, the following error occurred:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
bash: /usr/bin/yum: No such file or directory
```

I do to below command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip install yum
```

But, not succeed. Error is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yum (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yum
```

My python and pip version 2.7. and check versions 3.6 and 2.6.

What Should I Do?

Comment: Hi msp9011: yum: /etc/yum

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# /etc/yum -V
bash: /etc/yum: is a directory

Comment: [arcsight@localhost ~]$ rpm -q yum
package yum is not installed

Answer (score 1):

Seems `yum` is not installed... Try to download the rpm and install it.

- Download [this](https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm) for X64 or [this](https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.10/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm) for 32-bit
- Install with the command `rpm -i <yumPackageName>.rpm`
- And point python to 2.6

  `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python`

  `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: rpm -i yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-41.el6.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        yum >= 3.0 is needed by yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-41.el6.noarch how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you installing yum-plugin-fastestmirror rpm?

Comment: Because: The following errors are encountered during installation
[arcsight@localhost yum_cen]$ sudo rpm -i yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.1-10 is needed by yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch
        yum-plugin-fastestmirror is needed by yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch